# Parsing Multi-part in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to design a controller in Grails which accepts multipart like "XML+binary file1+binary file2+...". How could I parse this request? I appreciate any sample codes!

Thanks,
Reza

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried the way it shows [in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles)?

Comment: Yes. but the main issue is that I did not assign any form to it. The client just send http post with related data. I am not sure how could I use  def f = request.getFile('myFile') while I don't know its reference name. Any suggestions ('myFile'--->?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming you are talking about an input type file that has the multiple attribute. Here is how you would process it server side:

```
List<MultipartFile> files = request.multiFileMap.nameOfInputFileElement

files.each { uploadedFile ->

    if(!uploadedFile.empty){

        File newFile = new File( parentDir, uploadedFile.originalFilename)
        uploadedFile.transferTo(newFile)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the name of the files? In my case no form assigned to it. Just simple controller. The client just sends http multi-part post.

Comment: My advice would be to just set a break-point in the controller and see if you can find it in the request.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to unit test your codes in Grails?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
def uploadedFile = request.getFile('filepath')
    if (uploadedFile && !uploadedFile.empty)
        println "file:${uploadedFile?.originalFilename} uploaded"
    }
```